# Replicate Excel worksheets dynamically

Tags: php, excel, xlsx, tinybutstrong, opentbs

Is there any way to replicate Ms Excel worksheets dynamically, using openTBS on template side? im used to delimit this in Ms Word with 'Page Breaks' between the block begin and end...

What i need is

```
[base;block=begin]
"blablabla text...."
(Page Break)
[base;block=end]
```

So it can repeat all block on another page.

Is there any way to do that in Excel? But instead of a page break any other thing that will make that works in Excel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately OpenTBS cannot duplicate Ms Excel worksheets yet.

This can be done with ODS (LibreOffice) worksheets but not with Ms Excel because such worksheets are not saved in a single sub-file but in several sub-files which are all referenced in other sub-file. Thus, there is not TBS block defining a worksheet.

Nevertheless, instead of duplicate worksheets you can simulate duplication by add as much empty worksheets in the template as you may need. Then delete the useless worksheets during the merge using command OPENTBS_DELETE_SHEETS. Then copy the source of the worksheet from one to another using the property $TBS->Source. Copying source of worksheets can works if there is no object such as image or chart.